# Matlab Slider- Display left right arrows and move slider every 1 second

Tags: matlab, user-interface, timer, slider

As the title says I am using the GUIDE toolbox in Matlab and I would firstly like to know how I can display the left/right arrows at either end of the slider?

Also how can I get the slider to automatically move every 1 second?

As far as I understand it I need to first create a timer object and set the execution mode and period as follows:

```
time = timer;
set(time,'executionMode','fixedRate','period',1);
```

Now I know I need to set the timerFcn to something like:

```
set(handles.slider1,'Value',x);
```

in order to change the position of the slider.

Also I understand I need to increment the x variable first by the slider step which in my case is 0.00520833. For example:

```
x = x + 0.00520833;
```

So I have some code as follows:

```
time = timer;
set(time,'executionMode','fixedRate','period',1);
time.timerFcn = set(handles.slider1,'Value', x = x + 0.00520833); 
start(time);
```

However this doesn't work, and i'm sure it's because of something stupid that I am doing.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Now I can move the slider every second but what I would like to do is run a function of my own every second instead. For example:

```
time.timerFcn = @slider_increment;

function slider_increment

set(handles.slider1,'Value', get(handles.slider1,'Value') + 0.00520833)

slider = get(handles.slider1,'Value');
set(handles.text4,'String', slider);
```

I know this is a little messy but I will sort that later. The problem i'm facing is how to declare my own function inside the GUI script created by guide, and allow the function to access the handles to the GUI objects.

Comment: Doesn't work, or produces an error?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why are you wanting to automatically adjust the slider position? I ask because if you're trying to, for example, scroll advance a plot as new data is acquired, there's probably a better method.

Comment: Well tbh the slider is just a visual representation of the point in time for which the data is being displayed. But it further allows the user to choose a point in time. So yes, I am trying to show a series of plots with a new plot being displayed every second, but the slider will allow the user to choose a particular time also.

Answer (score 0):

First, this

```
time.timerFcn = set(handles.slider1,'Value', x = x + 0.00520833);
```

Definitely produces an error...

I think you want something like this:

```
h = uicontrol;

time = timer;
set(time,'executionMode','fixedRate','period',1);

%Note: set(h,val,get(h,val) + change)
time.timerFcn = @(x,y)set(h,'position', get(h,'position') + 10);

start(time);
```

Comment: thanks, this works perfectly however can you please tell me why the code under the "Executes on slider movement." part does not execute when the slider moves every second. It does execute when the slider is moved manually though... I need the slider to move every second and every time it moves I want to execute some code which will query a database and display a graph of the data. The slider is just a visual display of the current point in the data stream which is being graphed. Also manual movement of the slider should execute the code.

Comment: I don't know what this "Executes on slider movement." means.  Are you making a callback somewhere?  If so, the callback will only trigger when the slider is moved via human interaction.  You can get around this by making a new function  myFun.m, which will both (1) move the slider, and (2) manually call the slider callback.  This sounds like a separate StackOverflow question though.